# Multilevel and multivariate statistics

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, growth-model

I'm considering classes for next semester and I have a choice between 2:

1. Multivariate statistics and analysis
2. Hierarchical linear modeling and growth models

I'm wondering which of these courses are more foundational in terms of providing a solid grounding for future studies in statistics, and which is more useful generally in academia and industry data analysis contexts?

I would love to take both but my schedule does not permit that this term, so I'm looking to take the one that can set me up better for the future and is most used across a variety of disciplines. In my line of research (cognitive/health psychology) I see a pretty consistent split in how often these 2 techniques are used

Comment: 1. sounds more basic and could have broader coverage, while 2. seems more specific. For a good foundation for future studies in statistics, I would start with 1.

Comment: Seems like a tough call to me.  What level (undergrad, master's, PhD) are you at?  Maybe ask around among your colleagues and find out which instructor is better!